# Not able to create cross platform app in xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm new to xamarin and I'm trying to create cross platform App. In my Visual Studio there are only two options(Refer attached Image) but there should be option to create cross platform App too. I tried reinstalling mobile development with `.NET` and I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4dqH.png)

Comment: use the Xamarin Forms template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) is a cross-platform.  This allows you to use .NET with C#.  Please try creating anew Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms) project.  It should create an Android project, an iOS project, and shared UI project.  The shared project is where you will write the shared code for both projects.